# Facebook login popup doesn't work on ie6 and ie7?

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

Facebook login popup doesn't work on ie6 and ie7, are there some way to make the login popup with javascript sdk works in ie6 or ie7. Simply doesn't work and doesn't show any error. I'm using flash and javascript facebook sdk to prompt the login.

```
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId   : 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
              status  : true, // check login status
              cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
              channelUrl  : 'http://www.url.com/channel.html',
              oauth   : true
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
              alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
            });
          };

          (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
           }(document));

            function setFB(){
              FB.login(function(response) { 
                 if (response.authResponse) { 
                     FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
                            }); 
                  } else { obtenerDatos(false, "nologin", ""); } } 
             }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that opens the popup... You need to call the method FB.login

Comment: @BjörnKaiser yeap i doit in another js,
    FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    obtenerDatos(true, "silogin", response.name);
   });
  } else {
   obtenerDatos(false, "nologin", "");
  }
 }

Comment: Please add that JS code to your question as well. Do you may have some `console.log` statements in your code?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser nop i don't have any console.log. That i do is click on flash button that call the setFb function in javascript, but does not prompt the popup.

Comment: sorry for asking such a dumb question, but are you sure that the setFB function you're calling from Flash really gets executed?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser don't worry. Yeap because in chrome and firefox works perfect.

Comment: Do you have a link where we can have a look at your full code?

Comment: yeap, look in www.arequipealpina.com/beta

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code I see a console log in util_fb.js:48 which logs the text "executing get login". Maybe this will solve your issue.

It's in your getLogin() function.

Comment: yeap i'll put it in there about 2 minutes ago for see if it is calling.

Comment: Also checked if popups get blocked by IE?

Comment: i does but nothing the popup blocker was disabled

Comment: For me it worked well when testing, first it blocked the popup but after allowing popups for the site, the login popup showed up as usual :/

Comment: It seems that the error is only in ie6 that definitely doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Nice website by the way :-)